# Google Auth apis returns OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED 400

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-authentication

I am using this API
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY] 
 I have pass correct token and param same as in documentation but still, it `returns 400 OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED`

https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]

```
Param:-
{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "123123",
    "returnSecureToken": true
}

Response
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: are  you pass data in body..? if no please pass data in body. and also pass API_key in header

Comment: @imranali thank for a reply   I am passing data in body->raw->json using postman also pass API_key in a header but still not working.

Comment: That API doesn't exist anymore...according to Google https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to firebase console -> authentication -> sign-in method 
and then enable email/password providers

[image]